# console log works but return does not work in Meteor

Tags: meteor, return, react-hooks, console.log

I am using React Hook and trying to export a very simple method from a file into my component file.

I have a file called `get.js` where I have the following code.

```
import { Tracker } from 'meteor/tracker'
import { Tasks } from '../../tasks';

export default getTask = () => {
  Tracker.autorun(function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('taskList', function() {
      return Tasks.find({something: false}).fetch()
    })
  }
}
```

In another file, I import the `getTask` method and put it into the `useEffect` function

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import getTask from '../api/tasks/methods/get'

export default Tasks = () => {  
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    getTask()
  })
  return (
    <div>
     ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

My issue is in `get.js` file, if I try to do

```
console.log Tasks.find({something: false}).fetch()
```

It actually logs out the array of data I want. But if I do

```
return Tasks.find({something: false}).fetch()
```

I get undefined instead. How do I get the data to at least set state in my component file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is not the way subscriptions are meant to work in Meteor:

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  Meteor.subscribe('taskList', function() {
    return Tasks.find({something: false}).fetch()
  })
}
```

Subscriptions [return handles](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-subscribe) that switch state when ready. Also it seems, that you try to return data in a callback, [which basically does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function).

So in order to get this right, you can transform your method `getTask` to be stateless and subscribe to `taskList` globally:

```
import { Tasks } from '../../tasks';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('taskList')
})

export default getTask = () => Tasks.find({ something: false }).fetch()
```

Note that this is not reactive at all and Meteor offers a Tracker integration for react using `withTracker`: https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#using-withTracker